# Marking/retrieving a long array of numbers as "true/false" in postgres

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have a long list of indexes/numbers from `0 to 10 million`. I would like to mark each of these numbers as `true/false or set/unset`. I want to avoid creating a table with a row for everynumber like

```
CREATE TABLE foo (number integer, set boolean)
```

Instead, I was thinking that I could do some bitwise computation to store and retrive this data from a single cell. Can I use the `Bit(N)` data type here?

```
CREATE TABLE some_table (my_store BIT(1000000)) // 1 million
```

How should I go about setting/unsetting/retriving a bit value at a particular position?

**EDIT**

I found that `BIT(10000000)` gives an error  `is out of range for type integer`.

Comment: How many `set` and how many `unset`?

Comment: @Charlieface it starts with everything unset. Then I gradually set the indexes until everything is set

Comment: Well a row takes 23 bytes minimum plus an `int` size for this column. So if you just store the ones that are `set`, then you would have a table sized under 300MB, which isn't *that* big. A columnstore index would compress this down to a few KB.

Comment: Why not only store the numbers that are set?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name How do you suggest I store only numbers that are set?

Comment: @Charlieface eventually everything becomes set. But I get your point that there will be a reasonable upperbound (in this case 300 MB). Is there a way to avoid that? How can I leverage columnstore in postgres?

Comment: Only INSERT a row if the number is set. Numbers that don't exist in the table are unset. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=270381bf7eb04a6975afccb2051c1e23 - with an index on `number` this should be fairly quick if you only need to test single values.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yeah that's a solution. But eventually we set all the numbers so everything goes into the table. Is there away to avoid creating a new table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both, `bit` and `bit varying` type can store a bit mask of 10 million bits (the upper limit seems to be 83886080). But in order to be able to set/get bits in there, you need to pre-initialize the value. `set_bit()` won't automatically increase the size of the bit string (if using `bit varying`), and `get_bit()` will throw an error when trying to access a bit beyond the length of the current value.

```
create table numbers (flags bit(10000000));
insert into numbers (flags)
values (repeat('0', 10000000)::bit(10000000));
```

That creates a single bit string with 10 million bits (all set to zero).

Note that the numbering of the bits starts at `0`, not 1. So to test for the "last value" you need:

```
select get_bit(flags, 10e6::int - 1)
from numbers;
```

To change a value, use `set_bit()` to set the bit for Number 10000

```
update numbers
   set flags = set_bit(flags, 10000 - 1, 1)
```

You can wrap the logic into functions if you want.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d3e37762c1610f1aaa5312e5194566b5)

In theory you could use a `bit varying` to support an unknown range of numbers, you just need to have some logic that extends the current value to include the new bit position e.g. by appending the appropriate number of bits between the new one and the existing ones to "fill the gap".

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. Btw, is this way of using bits less performant than the solution using rows (indexed)?

Comment: @Ashwin: not sure. The solution with a bit string needs to rewrite the entire string (64kb) each time you want to update one value but is way more space efficient. If you store it in rows, an update of a single value only changes a (small) single row.

Comment: Why does it have to re-write the entire string? It just has to set the bit at a particular position right?

Comment: Because it's a single column. If you change a column, the whole column is written back to disk (in reality it's even the whole row). If you change a `text` column from `'bar`'  to `'bas'`  it also need to write the entire string, not just the changed character